# Aforge not working with transparency

Tags: c#, image, aforge, distortion

Hopefully someone can help me with this. I have a code that is working perfectly with pictures without transparency. As soon as I try to do it with a picture that includes tranparency it does not do anything. I tried also to run it with a "png" picture but with out transparency and it works. It just looks that it does not like the tranparency.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using AForge;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge.Imaging.ComplexFilters;
using AForge.Imaging.ColorReduction;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;

namespace TextoToImage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        Bitmap bitmap_profile = new Bitmap(@"c:\Path\pic1.png");
        Bitmap image_background = new Bitmap(@"c:\Path\pic2.jpg");

        List<IntPoint> corners = new List<IntPoint>();
        corners.Add(new IntPoint(611, 27));
        corners.Add(new IntPoint(354, 27));
        corners.Add(new IntPoint(367, 394));
        corners.Add(new IntPoint(655, 395));
        BackwardQuadrilateralTransformation filter = new BackwardQuadrilateralTransformation(bitmap_profile, corners);
        Bitmap newImage = filter.Apply(image_background);

        newImage.Save(@"c:\Path\output_pic.png");
        }
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide